# How to hide the legend with uvCharts in R or Javascript

Tags: javascript, r, hide, legend, rcharts

I am using uvCharts via RCharts in R.  All I want to do is be able to hide the legend on a bar chart when I need it.  Below is the code and example from http://rcharts.io/howitworks/part2/ (I don't think I can insert images yet).  If you scroll to about the middle of the page you see the bar chart with a legend with Brown, Blue, Hazel, and Green.

```
hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
dataset = make_dataset('Hair', 'Freq', hair_eye_male, group = 'Eye')
u1 <- uPlot("Hair", "Freq", 
  data = hair_eye_male, 
  group = "Eye",
  type = 'StackedBar'
)
u1$config(meta = list(
  caption = "Hair vs. Eye Colors",
  vlabel  = "Hair Color"
))
u1$config(graph = list(
  palette = "Olive"  
))
u1
```

Does anyone know how to hide the legend in uvCharts?  I know I could do a

```
u1$config(legend = list())
```

but the documentation (http://imaginea.github.io/uvCharts/documentation.html) doesn't really give any further information about the legends.  Any information as to how to do this in R or JavaScript would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
u1$config(legend = list(
  showlegends = false
))
```

In uvCharts, one would have to pass it as a config property

```
{
   legend: {
      showlegends: false
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, I really appreciate it!